# Colorbox elements retaining old value

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to create a modal window with colorbox to change a report title by placing a textarea in the colorbox as follows.

```
<a class="change-report-title" href="#edit-box">Change Title</a>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(".change-report-title").colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    width:"400px",
    onOpen:function(){  
        var current_title = $("#report-title").html();
        $("#title-box-text").html(current_title);
    }
});
```

**html:**

```
   <div style="display:none">
       <div id="edit-box"> 
       Edit Report Title<br />
       <textarea id="title-box-text" name="title-box-text" cols="38" rows="5"></textarea>
       <br />
       <input id="title-box-change" name="title-box-change" type="button" value="Update" />
       </div>
   </div>
```

I tried to get the report title when loading colorbox and it works fine
Now trying to update the title with the edited valued of the textarea, the textarea keep returning the very first value.

```
$("#title-box-change").click(function (e) {
    var new_title = $("#title-box-text").html();
    $("#report-title").html(new_title);
    return false;
});
```

There is something I'm not just getting right, I have googled and searched stackoverflow.
Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the `.change-report-title` element exist? Please add its definition in the question.

Comment: Definition now added: `.change-report-title` element is the link used to invoke the colorbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `val()` function instead of `html()`. Also it would be better to use the text() method instead of html() if you need to get/set text (not html markup).

For the first part of code:

```
var current_title = $("#report-title").text();
                                      ^^^^^^^
$("#title-box-text").val(current_title);
                     ^^^^
```

For a click event:

```
$("#title-box-change").click(function (e) {
    var new_title = $("#title-box-text").val();
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
    $("#report-title").text(new_title);
                       ^^^^^
    return false;
});
```